# How come the answer to "how much" here is countable?

Tags: grammaticality

I came across this sentence in an exercise:

> - [Blank] yogurt do you need?
>
>   - Three cups.

The options for the blank are the following:

> A. How long B. How far C. How many D. How much

The answer is D, but why is answered by "three cups"?

Comment: I've altered the question title here so as to make it more specific to your question.

Answer (score 6):

When you quantify a mass noun, you need to use a count noun to do it.

> How much fruit did you get? Three **pieces** of fruit.
>   How much gasoline does your tank hold? Fifty **liters** of gasoline.
>   How much sugar do you take in your coffee? Two **cubes** of sugar.
>   How much ice cream should I get you? Three **scoops** of ice cream.
>   How much rice do you have?  Half a **cup** of rice (or 3600 **grains** of rice).
>   How much corn? Ten **ears** of corn (or 70 **kernels** of corn).
>   How much garlic? Five **cloves** of garlic (or one **bulb** of garlic).
>   How much rain? Twenty **drops** of rain (or three **inches** of rain, or forty **days** of rain).

So *"three cups of yogurt"* is a perfectly normal phrase in English. Here, a *cup* is probably a unit of measure used in America equal to approximately 1/4 liter.

Note that some mass nouns require rather specific count nouns (e.g. *"ears of corn"*) to quantify them.

Comment: Note that "cattle" doesn't belong here. While **head** is commonly used as a "unit" of cattle, it's also perfectly fine to speak of **four cattle**, and the question **How many** is a giveaway.

Comment: @chrylis: I think that "head of cattle" is likely to be an expression left over from a time when "cattle" was a real mass noun; that is, "four cattle" may not have been used in some regions and times. Compare with [pieces of cannon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4568/cannon-as-plural). But you're right; *"four cattle"* is fine today. I have replaced "cattle" with some other mass nouns in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Yogurt** in this case is treated as a mass noun, like many English words referring to a bulk product. (*Yogurts* is a word, but it refers to a collection of different types or containers of yogurt.) You're correct that the answer is D, because mass nouns are uncountable, and **how much** is used for measured amounts.

**Three cups** is simply a measurement of volume (about 0.7 liter), and when mass nouns of physical objects are quantified, it's usually by either volume or mass (weight).

Comment: The explanation in Collins Cobuild Dictionary about Yogurt is: Yogurt is a food in the form of a thick, slightly sour liquid that is made by adding bacteria to milk. A yogurt is a small pot of yogurt.

Comment: Yogurt is treated as a mass noun, it should be uncountable, but why can we use the expression " a yogurt " ?

Comment: @user48070 Edited slightly. Many mass nouns that refer to semi-continuous physical objects can be used as countable nouns if you're discussing either types or servings of the object. As the CCD mentioned, *a* yogurt (countable) is a single serving of yogurt (uncountable).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer the OP's question left as a comment but I will also tie it in with the main question.

> Yogurt is treated as a mass noun, it should be uncountable, but why
>   can we use the expression " a yogurt "

If you were to pour a large pot of yoghurt on a flat surface such as a plate, it would be very difficult to quantify. Yoghurt doesn't separate itself, it's one entire *mass* and hence *it* (the yoghurt) is recognizable as being singular. In order to quantify this thick sloppy substance you might say; there's *a lot of* yoghurt on the plate; that's *quite a bit*; the plate is *almost full* etc. But plates come in different sizes and what is a lot for one person, is "normal" for another. You could however take a cup and proceed to fill it. The number of filled cups is the *quantity* of the yoghurt, e.g. three cups.

Luckily, yoghurt is sold in standard-sized pots, and not in cups. A single pot is enough to contain 150g of yoghurt. A large yoghurt pot will usually contain 500g. Pots are countable, we can buy **one pot of** yoghurt or **two pots**. Hence

- one / a **pot** of yoghurt
- two **pots** of yoghurt

Note that the word, yoghurt, is singular and it will remain in the singular regardless of the number of pots:
 "I'd like fifty pots of strawberry yoghurt"
The British and Americans being two populations famed for their love of brevity and taking short-cuts will simply say

- "**a** yoghurt"
- "two **yoghurts**"

The meaning therefore is clear, unambiguous and also grammatical.

Comment: On a related note, just the other day I referred to two one-pound packages of ground beef as *two beefs*.  The person I was talking to knew what I meant, so it was okay, though of course it was non-standard.  A third person who was present was, for some reason, very amused by me saying *two beefs*.

Comment: Maybe "beef" is slang for something... I'll look into it. :)

Comment: @snailboat Clearly the third person had a beef with that mode of expression.